# RAD sequencing: choosing the appropriate enzyme?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, genomics, restriction-enzymes

I’m studying Darwin’s finches genome and I say in some articles that the researchers used restriction enzymes to cut the DNA in their double digest RAD protocol. They are using [EcoRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EcoRI) and [MseI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_restriction_enzyme_cutting_sites:_L%E2%80%93N#M) (GAATTC and TTAA), the two enzymes similar and used in `Peterson, B. K., J. N. Weber, E. H. Kay, H. S. Fisher, and H. E. Hoekstra. 2012. Double digest RADseq: an inexpensive method for de novo SNP discovery and genotyping in model and non-model species. PLoS ONE 7:e37135.` (they are using EcoRI and [MspI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_restriction_enzyme_cutting_sites:_L%E2%80%93N#M) (GAATTC and CCGG).

Considering the huge list of [restriction enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_restriction_enzyme_cutting_sites:_E%E2%80%93F#Whole_list_navigation) how to choose the appropriate enzyme? Is it a complete guess? The size of the genome of finches is about 1.07Gb. Do I have to take this in consideration?

The reference genome is available `Zhang, G., P. Parker, B. Li, H. Li, and J. Wang. 2012. The genome of Darwin’s Finch (Geospiza fortis). GigaScience.`

Comment: maybe R.EcoRII or FokI/Taq52I?

Comment: Why would you choose these?

Comment: R.EcoRII because of its molecular mass (45.2 kDa), it targets CCWGG, C-terminal domain of restriction endonuclease and apologies, I meant Tsp49I rather than Taq52I and this because of its relatively high pH optimum, reaching enzyme activity peak at rather "high" temperatures, its a thermostable neoschizomer